# binary ownership in a romfs package

Tags: linux, kernel

I inherited an old system and I am still getting a hold of how the system works. Its a custom linux running built on AT91. We build a romfs and package in a bunch of binaries that gets installed upon flashing. I have been building as a root because I that is how it was inherited and done in the past. The binaries that get packed into the romfs are listed in a Makefile with individual file privileges/permissions.

When the romfs gets flashed and all the binaries get installed they have the permissions set to root:root. I understand romfs-inst.sh script does set some permissions through the many options it provides and those are being set right.

I need to be able to install the binaries are someuser:somegroup and I am sure there is no chown kind of option in the romfs-inst.sh. How else do I change the owner and group of the binaries.

Any help is appreciated Thanks

Answer (score 0):

romfs doesn't have any way of storing the owner of a file. (It doesn't even preserve permissions other than the execute bit.)

If you need these features, you should probably take a look at replacing romfs with [cramfs](http://lxr.linux.no/linux/Documentation/filesystems/cramfs.txt) or [squashfs](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v4.10.1/Documentation/filesystems/squashfs.txt). Along with supporting ownership and permissions, these filesystems can also compress files, letting you store more data in the same amount of memory.

Comment: Then where is it getting the root:root privileges from? Is it inherited because I built it as a root? Or does the build just default it to root?

Comment: It's implied for all files in a romfs.

Comment: Should rephrase, where from are the binaries getting root:root privileges?

Comment: Ah, ok, I am short on time to understand and implement cramfs, probably I have a couple of days. Would it possible to move the romfs implementation to cramfs in such a short time or instead as temporary solution should I just execute a script, after the romfs gets unzipped, to change the binary permissions?

Comment: You can't modify files in a mounted romfs at all -- not even their permissions/ownership. The filesystem isn't being "unzipped"; it's being presented directly from the romfs archive, which can't be modified. Implementing tooling for cramfs or squashfs should be easy; they work very similarly to romfs.

Comment: (Note: I've added a recommendation for SquashFS. Very similar to cramfs, but a bit more modern.)

Comment: Thank you for your comments. That gets me going forward.